# bcrypt in python

Tags: python, security, hash, bcrypt

At the moment I'm trying to build a log in system with a very high security.

So I want to use bcrypt and I've also found a 3rd party library, 
[py-bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/).

But the author said it is a pure python implementation.

Now I read somewhere that it is not recommended to use bcrypt in python only because it is too slow and this results in a security leak. bcrypt should be implemented in C.

Can anyone confirm this?  Now what should I do?

**Should I use:**

- bcrypt (python)
- SHA512 (from hashlib)
- something different

*I'm using Google App Engine*

**EDIT:**
http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html#bcrypt-backends

> It should be noted that the pure-python implementation (#4) is too
>   slow to be useable, given the number of rounds currently required for
>   security. Because of this, it is disabled by default, unless the
>   environment variable PASSLIB_BUILTIN_BCRYPT="enabled" is set.

Comment: Why would "being slow" be considered a security leak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about comparing the two? Here is code to hash a password of 8000 random bits and corresponding times:

Hashlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hashlib
import random

password = str(random.getrandbits(8000))
print hashlib.sha512(password).hexdigest()
```

Hashlib including salt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hashlib
import random

password = str(random.getrandbits(8000))
salt = str(random.getrandbits(256))
print hashlib.sha512(password + salt).hexdigest()
```

bcrypt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bcrypt
import random

password = str(random.getrandbits(8000))
print bcrypt.hashpw(password,bcrypt.gensalt())
```

Timing bcrypt:

```
$ time ./bcrypt_test.py 
$2a$12$Om3a3zKsCNAM/SLB3hq5w.HYukFwn4CJ73rjXYNUPgqckUx2uLEmG

real    0m0.401s
user    0m0.313s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Timing hashlib:

```
$ time ./hashlib_test.py 
9e37eb4f164bbb1808833297d0244327e4faac109cd92729228f6e36d75d23044ac13a7a1907515cd6db44474b244678779e3ae4e97d8355c2069332aae52d61

real    0m0.032s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m0.010s
$
```

Comment: I modified the hashlib script to also include a 32 byte salt, and the numbers are still more or less the same

Comment: okay now bcrypt runs 10times slower than sha512 which is better for brutforce attacks. but the sha512 has 128 letters , shouldn't this outweight bcrypt even with brutforce attacks ?

Comment: The 128 character string is actually a hex representation of the byte hash. So effectively the password is 64 characters long, not 128. The bcrypt output is more or less the same length.

Comment: @Chopstick Using a hash function on a password once is **completely insecure** and an absolutely unacceptable way of "storing" a password. If you're interested in a **safe** simple hash-based password storage scheme, you can use PBKDF2 with a large (5- or 6-digit) number of rounds, though bcrypt is an even better solution. [Edit: This should be directed to the OP as well. I reacted to your answer more since it contained actual code.]

Comment: @MattNordhoff You're absolutely right. I should have made sure my example also covered the crypto aspects of it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Chopstick I apologize for jumping on you. I've apparently recently become a grumpy password storage zealot (the zealotry is good; the grumpiness is not) and I didn't realize when first writing my comment that the "single hash" thing was originally proposed by the OP, so I blamed you for coming up with it. (Edit: Not that my explanation/excuse makes being rude *okay*.)

Comment: @MattNordhoff It's all good; glad you did in a way. I work in the security industry & I should have known better. You weren't rude... compared with some of the folks in the industry that I know I'd say you were downright neighbourly.

Comment: Worth noting that bcrypt will truncate passwords longer than 72 characters. a 1000 character password will unfairly favor a SHA512. Also, this is an apples to oranges comparison. The python bcrypt implementation needs to be compared to the C level or standard implementation. If the python implementation were significantly slower, a security risk become apparent, if the application takes 1 second to run the alg., but an attacker runs the same alg. in .05 ms.

Answer (score 5):

Try [passlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib/). It has a C implementation of [bcrypt](http://packages.python.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.bcrypt.html).